# Angular ngx-scrollbar throwing error inside other components

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I am trying to use ngx-scrollbar in one of the component but when I am using on the other component it is throwing error

ngx-scroolbar: 4.1.1
Angular: 7

```
exampleComponent.ts

<div>
<ng-scroolbar [autohide]=true > </ng -scrollbar>
</div>
```

s

```
someothercomponet.ts

<example-component></example-component>
```

I am getting the below error in the browser console of the ngx-scroolbar.js

```
get view() {
    return this.customViewPort
        ? this.customViewPort.virtualScrollViewport.getElementRef().nativeElement
        : this.scrollViewport.getElementRef().nativeElement;
}
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementRef' of undefined**
    at NgScrollbar.get view [as view] (ngx-scrollbar.js:365)
    at NgScrollbar.showScrollbarY (ngx-scrollbar.js:398)
    at Object.updateRenderer (ngx-scrollbar.d.ts.NgScrollbar.html:19)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:47005)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:45987)
    at callViewAction (core.js:46347)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:46304)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:45982)
    at callViewAction (core.js:46347)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:46275)
```

Comment: When is your `view` getter being called/referenced? References to elements (typically) aren't available until after the view has been initialized.

Comment: Could you please elaborate when the view is initialized? updated the error trace

Comment: Definitely! I have a hunch that what is happening is this: your `view` getter is being called/referenced _before_ any DOM elements have been created for your component. This means that (at this point) your `customViewPort` and `scrollViewport` ViewChildren (I'm assuming that's what they are, but please correct me if that's not the case) are not yet defined. In this case, fixing it might be as simple as provided an early exit in your `view` getter if neither of those variables is defined.

Comment: The view is managed on the ngx-scrollbar.js. How do we control the early exit of the view.Could you just give me an example..?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been terribly clear with my language here. Which component did you define the `get view() { ... }` getter on? Is there any way you could show more of the .ts and .html files for this component?